# Oneplus 6 gets stuck on Fastboot Mode when booting to TWRP after system update

Tags: twrp, oneplus-6

After upgrading my Oneplus 6 to Android 10 from Android Pie using the System Updater, I tried to reinstall TWRP using the both the most up to date image from https://dl.twrp.me/enchilada/. I tried both the most up to date image and the one I had used previously to install TWRP.

When I run `fastboot boot twrp.img` in the bootloader, it gets stuck on "Fastboot Mode". If I hold the power button, the phone turns off and I can boot it again normally. How do I boot to TWRP properly?

Comment: follow install instructions on xda support thread https://twrp.me/oneplus/oneplus6.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between twrp-\[version\]-\[phone\].img and twrp-installer-\[version\]-\[phone\].zip?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/220359/what-is-the-difference-between-twrp-version-phone-img-and-twrp-installer-ve)

Comment: No - I know the difference between the .img and .zip and I am trying to boot from the .img file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem by using the TWRP link from [this](https://androidfilehost.com/?fid=4349826312261707803) website which I got to from [this](https://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-6/how-to/how-to-flash-twrp-magisk-android-10-t3988213) xda page. It got past fastboot mode and into TWRP.