# Unable to root Motorola G7 Power XT1955-4

Tags: rooting, motorola

I am trying to follow this tutorial https://aiomobilestuff.com/motorola-moto-g7-power-xt-1955-root-twrp-unlock-bootloader/

The command

```
fastboot flash recovery twrp.img
```

(I renamed my twrp.img to recovery.img)
gives me this error

[image]

and the command

```
fastboot boot twrp.img
```

boots my phone into twrp and it freezes it.
I am able to work again with my phone only after restart.
Is there a way so that I could root my phone?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between twrp-\[version\]-\[phone\].img and twrp-installer-\[version\]-\[phone\].zip?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/220359/what-is-the-difference-between-twrp-version-phone-img-and-twrp-installer-ve)

Comment: linked tutorial is invalid/untested. this device has no recovery partition. follow the official [TWRP](https://twrp.me/motorola/motorolamotog7power.html) install instructions. please note according to xda [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3963738) touch screen may not work, you have to use [commandline](https://twrp.me/faq/openrecoveryscript.html) to install. for unlocking bootloader read [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=4019903)